# AngularJS 'if the directive is deleted so we don't introduce a memory leak'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks

From AngularJS developer guide documentation on [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) there is an instruction saying:
...

> if the directive is deleted so we don't introduce a memory leak

Can anybody elaborate on this. How can a directive be deleted, it's there in the first place in the template to provide dynamic functionalities to HTML. Now as I understand a directive can modify an element and delete it. But why should it delete itself?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand it now. I think it would be rather

> if the DOM node or a service is deleted to which we register a listener, we don't introduce a memory leak. Now look carefully at following codes.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-controller="MyController">
            Date format: <input ng-model="format"> <hr>
            Current time is: <span my-current-time="format"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    angular.module('app', [])

    .controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
      $scope.format = 'M/d/yy h:mm:ss a';
    })

    .directive('myCurrentTime', ['$interval', 'dateFilter', function($interval, dateFilter) {
      return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          var format, timeoutId;

          function updateTime() {
            console.log('hi');
            element.text(dateFilter(new Date(), format));
          }

          scope.$watch(attrs.myCurrentTime, function(value) {
            format = value;
            updateTime();
          });

          /*element.on('$destroy', function () {
            console.log('hello');
            $interval.cancel(timeoutId);
          });*/

          timeoutId = $interval(function () {
            updateTime();
          }, 1000);

          element.remove();
        }
      };
    }]);
</script>
</html>
```

Here we have commented out the code that should clean the listeners that are registered on the DOM node. At the end of the code we have manually removed the `DOM node`. After removing the `DOM node`, the `updateTime` function should no longer be called. But it keeps calling the `updateTime` function as we can see in the `console`.
But if we remove the comments from the commented out code, it handles cleaning up the registration of the listeners. And as you can see in the console, the `updateTime` function is no longer called after removal of the node at the end of the code.